# Persistent Qtip

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I want to use [Qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) to display a *persistent* tool tip. By persistent I mean that the tool tip should be shown when the page is loading and then it should neither be hidden nor destroyed for the lifetime of the page. I have tried the solution [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-persistent-tooltip) but it did not work for me. In my code which you can refer it at jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dav_evans/KHxgQ/), the tool tip is still hidden when the target is moused over. I want this behavior to be off so that the tool tip stays in place.

for your reference,to help me,code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip_new/packages/nightly/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="mycss2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        #demo-simple{
            margin:100px;
            border:1px red Solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo-simple" class="box">
        <div id="primary">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip_new/packages/nightly/jquery.qtip.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#primary").qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'I am primary'
                },
                show: {
                    ready: false,
                    delay: 0
                },
                hide: {
                    when: false
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'right center',
                    at: 'left center',
                    target: $('#primary')
                },
            });
            $("#primary").qtip('show');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make the tooltip permanent upon page load. 
[JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KHxgQ/9/)

```
$("#primary").qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I am primary'
    },
    show: {
        ready: true,
        delay: 0
    },
    hide: false,
    position: {
        my: 'right center',
        at: 'left center',
        target: $('#primary')
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/KHxgQ/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#primary").qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'I am primary'
        },
        show: true,
        hide: false,
        position: {
            my: 'right center',
            at: 'left center',
            target: $('#primary')
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Tooltip isnt shown on page load, I assume ready:true would fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 show: {
   ready: true,
   delay: 0
 },
 hide: {
   event: 'nonexisting'
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHxgQ/8/